# upgraded to xcode 4.2 now exc_bad_access on dimissModalViewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, exc-bad-access

Hi I'm having a weird problem.

My app is based on the samplecode of "PageControl" (the Apple example). 
It uses a horizontal scrollview in which most of the stuff is happening.
At he bottom I have a UIToolbar from which I call a modal viewcontroller.

On XCode 4 everything worked like a charm, after the upgrade to XCode 4.2 (with the new SDK) I get a "exc_bad_access" on dimissModalViewcontroller. 
The funniest thing is that it does not happen rightaway but only after 2 or 3 times presenting and dismissing the modalViewcontroller.

To simplify things I went back to the original samplecode and tried to implement the modalVieWcontroler in that context. No luck so far.

In the original PageControl Code I changed the type of "ContentController" from NSObject to UIViewController like so:

```
@interface ContentController : UIViewController
{
    NSArray *contentList;
}
```

I call presentModalViewcontroller in a sub class (from ContentController) named PhoneContentController like so:(I use a notification so I can call it from anywhere)

```
-(void) showExplanationsModal:(NSNotification*)notification{

    ExplanationsViewController *xplViewController = [[[ExplanationsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Explanations" bundle:nil]autorelease];

    [self presentModalViewController:xplViewController animated:YES];
}
```

The dismissal of the modalViewcontroller is called from the modal view itself like so:
(the notification is used tot initiate some other stuff)

```
 - (IBAction)onClose
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"dismissExplanationsModal" object:self];

}
```

This code works fine with iOS4 SDK but renders occasional excec_bad_access with iOS5 SDK.
When I compile the app with iOS4 SDK it also rus fine on iOS5 devices.
I tried using Zombies but this does not point to a specific over-released object.
I'm sort of stuck on this one for a few days already ...

I have put up a copy of a sample project that illustrates the problem  here http://www.sesni.biz/pagecontrol.zip

Comment: this is just a total guess, but dismissing modal view controllers changed in iOS5. the docs say if you call dismiss on the modal view controller, then it will forward that to the parent view controller. but i've found that dismiss needs to be called on the presenting view controller (they're now different). maybe try `[[self presentingViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` ?

Comment: Hmm. No luck. I tried dismissing from the presenting viewcontroller directly as well, also with the same result but thanks anyway,

Comment: Try saving all your code to a text file and reinstalling Xcode...

Comment: The dismiss and present code works fine when used on a standard viewController so the problem must lie in the combination of Apples "PageControl" sample code and the modalView implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: I changed the type of ContententController from NSObject to UIViewcontroller. This worked fine with the iOS4 SDK but crashes with iOS5 SDK.

Answer (score 1):

It seems for me that problem is in the `onClose` method.  Try first sending the message, without the object (this object will be invalidated soon).

```
 - (IBAction)onClose
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"dismissExplanationsModal" object:nil];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Your solution sounded plausible but again no succes, The app even crashes with the notification removed. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It's important information. Check `dealloc` and `viewDidUnload` methods of this modalViewcontroller.

Comment: I'm running a test setup now with practically no functionality so there is nothing in the dealloc and viewDidUnload methods except for [super dealloc] and [super viewDidUnload]

Comment: I have put up a copy of a sample project that illustrates the problem here: [link](http://www.sesni.biz/pagecontrol.zip)